# Why does changing the order of calling std::regex::str and std::regex::suffix change the behaviour?

Tags: c++, regex

I've written some working code that prints out every occurrence of 2 vowels in a row.

```
std::regex x("(a|e|i|o|u){2}");

std::smatch r;

std::string t = some_string;

while (std::regex_search(t, r, x)) {
    std::cout << "match: " << r.str() << '\n';

    t = r.suffix();
}
```

But when I change the order like this:

```
while (std::regex_search(t, r, x)) {
    t = r.suffix();

    std::cout << "match: " << r.str() << '\n';
}
```

it suddenly starts giving random results. I don't see the connection between these 2 lines, and why changing their order would affect anything. Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This statement:

```
    t = r.suffix();
```

isn't creating a new string object, or changing what string object `t` denotes, or anything like that; rather, it's mutating the existing string object by copying over the contents of `r.suffix()`.

And `r` doesn't hold the actual string data; it just holds index information so that the appropriate string data can be extracted from `t`. Mutating `t` essentially invalidates the old indices, so you get the wrong string data.